# raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have problem to raise notice when exception occurs.
Lets say that my query has two inserts statements.

```
      do $$       
      begin
        insert into ...
        insert into ...
      exception when others then 
        raise notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
      end; $$ 
      language 'plpgsql';
```

I want to return error message and code.
Currently nothing happen. IF I remove 'notice '% %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;'
then error is raised but I need to catch it. Seems that 'notice' does not work.
This is what I have got in response

```
{"command":"BEGIN","rowCount":null,"oid":null,"rows":[],"fields":[],"_parsers":[],"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":true}
{"command":"LOCK","rowCount":null,"oid":null,"rows":[],"fields":[],"_parsers":[],"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":true}
{"command":"DO","rowCount":null,"oid":null,"rows":[],"fields":[],"_parsers":[],"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":true}
{"command":"COMMIT","rowCount":null,"oid":null,"rows":[],"fields":[],"_parsers":[],"RowCtor":null,"rowAsArray":true}
```

Postgres 9.4

Comment: `set client_min_messages=notice;`?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happen". How are you executing it, where are you looking for something to happen?